# Integrating vector fields over higher-dimensional surfaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I know how to integrate both scalar and vector functions over 2-dimensional surfaces. The way to do that is the same explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral 
The thing is that it uses cross product of the parametrization to get a normal vector of norm 1, so how should I generalise it for higher dimensions?

I have heard something about a so called "fundamental form" to generalise these kind of things, but I don't remember exactly

Comment: Can you give an example problem?

Comment: Sure. For instance $$\int_{S_R ^n (0)} \frac{1}{|x|^n} d \delta$$ where $S_R ^n (0)$ is the n-dimensional hypersphere of radius R centered in 0.

Comment: I mean, I can't do any cross product in dimensions different than 3

Comment: Ok maybe that one is a little easy, cause that norm is always the same and it is also a scalar field, not a vector one. Let’s say I want to integrate over that surface the vector field $F(x_1, \dots,x_n)=(x_1 ^2,\dots, x_n ^2)$. Maybe this one is very hard, idk, the thing is I would like to know how to do this in theory AND with some easy (but not trivial) examples

Comment: Basically: what you can integrate over $n$-dimensional objects are "differential forms" of degree $n$. In $\Bbb R^n$, for example, you can identify $1$-forms and $(n-1)$-forms with vector fields. Look up Loring Tu's Introduction to Manifolds.